# Hide row in Excel if 3 of the cells are blank

Tags: excel, hide, vba

I have a Sheet with columns A through F. I'm looking for the program to run through all the rows (Is there a way for it to only do active rows?) and check if D1 & E1 & F1 are blank, then hide the row (and so on).

Here's what I have which doesn't really work too well....

```
 Sub Celltest2()
 Dim rw As Range, cel As Range
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim celset As Range

 For Each rw In Sheets("Phonelist").Range("D2:F5000").Rows
    For Each cel In rw.Cells
            If Len(cel.Text) = 0 Then
            cel.EntireRow.Hidden = True

            End If
    Next
Next
 End Sub
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work too well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
Sub Celltest2()

Dim rw As Range, cel As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim celset As Range
Dim LastRow As Long


With Sheets("Phonelist")
    ' find last row with data in Columns "D, "E" and "F" >> modify to your needs
    LastRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row, _
                                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row, _
                                    .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row)

    For Each rw In .Range("D2:F" & LastRow).Rows
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("D" & rw.Row & ":F" & rw.Row)) = 0 Then
            rw.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next rw
End With

End Sub
```

**Option 2**: You can replace the loop above (the one that starts with `For Each rw In .Range("D2:F" & LastRow).Rows`) with the following loop:

```
For i = 2 To LastRow
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("D" & i & ":P" & i)) = 0 Then
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next i
```